# Xcode doesn’t support iOS 15.0

Tags: ios15, xcode12.5

I updated my iPhone to iOS 15.0 yesterday and I wanted to build in Xcode (version 12.5.1).
But in Xcode it is showing 'iPhone (unsupported OS version)' and when I try to build (command + R) then I get the error:

> Xcode doesn’t support iPhone’s iOS 15.0 (19A346).

Is there a way to use it without downgrading iOS?

Comment: Only other option is to update to [Xcode 13](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)

Comment: @shim Thank you. I'll try it!

Comment: Updating xcode is safer solution than downloading random iOS image to launch it on the phone (As the answer below suggests). The update should include latest iOS image for development.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Without updating Xcode, you need to put the relevant device file in the DeviceSupport section and run Xcode again. DeviceSupport files are located here.

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport

You can download iOS15 devicesupport file from here, then you need to unzip, then you need to put it in DeviceSupport section on your mac.

When you restart Xcode, there should be no problem.

**Update for iOS 15.1**

For 15.1 devices, You can copy file from 15.0 to the same directory as 15.1. Then you need to open Xcode again, it should be fine.

Comment: Showed a weird error the first time, so I closed out Xcode and ran it again. Had to copy cache files from phone, then it worked.

Comment: Do the same steps apply for building / archiving an ipa for an iOS 15 device ? I do not have an iOS 15 device with me so it would be nice to know if there are additional steps. Thanks

Comment: it doesn't work with a device running IOS  15.1.1, do you have an update for it?

Comment: @Jonathan , For iOS 15.1.1, you can make a copy of 15.0. You have to name this copy 15.1. Then restart xCode and there should be no problem.

Comment: How do you navigate to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` ? In my Applications folder I don't see anything

Comment: on terminal use 
1. cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform 2. open .

Comment: You really saved my day. This answer is far better than the answers given by whole apple support team on their brag box.

Update xcode update iphone update your Mac and what not...
literally they have more tantrum than girlfriend.

Comment: What to do with "iOS deployment target" in setting? It doesn't show the version that I've installed.

Comment: Woks like charm! IOS 15.4

Comment: Such weird solution to follow, downloading a random iOS image to run it on the device isn't the best thing due to security concerns. You can upgrade xcode from app store and that should include latest very trusted official image of iOS device support.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer's repository doesn't include some of the latest versions like 16.1, here is a more updated one:

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport